# Desplazar los bits de un int

Tags: python, números-enteros

Quiero desplazar los bits que conforman un `int` utilizando el operador `<<` sin que el número de bits que conforman el entero aumenten. Por ejemplo:

```
i = 5 #101 en binario
i = i << 2
print bin(i)
```

Quiero que los bits que conforman `i` adquieran el valor `100` correspondiente a desplazar los 3 bits iniciales. Sin embargo, lo que ocurre es que añade dos ceros a la derecha, con los que los bits de `i` finalmente son `10100`.

Entiendo que esto ocurre porque el desplazamiento binario es análogo a multiplicar, de ahí que añada los ceros, pero no sé como quedarme con el número de bits que yo desee.

Comment: No te entiendo, cual es la salida que deseas

Comment: @eyllanesc  Quiero que desplace los bits de `i` quedándome solo con los 3 bits menos significativos.

Comment: Prueba con mi solución :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si deseas eliminar bits innecesarios debes usar la operacion `and` con la mascara adecuada:

```
i = 5 #101 en binario
i = (i << 2) & 7 # 7 es 00111
print(bin(i))
```

Output:

```
0b100
```

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que aplicar lo que se conoce como máscara. Ejemplo en C:

```
int main()
{
    int i = 5;
    i = i << 2; // 10100
    i = i & 7; // 10100 & 00111 => 100

    printf("Valor de i: %d.", i);

    return 0;
}
```

**Salida**: "Valor de i: 4".